# GraphQL sorting of queries broken on Neo4j Aura

Tags: neo4j, graphql, neo4j-aura

It appears that GraphQL-queries with sort are broken on Neo4j Aura.

A GraphQL call that was working for months now suddenly fails.

The main error message that comes back is: `Neo4jError: Unknown function 'apoc.coll.sortMulti'`

Queries that fail have this shape:

```
{
  Unit {
    SHOWS_rel(orderBy: order_asc) {
      Image {
        id
        url
      }
      order
    }
  }
}
```

Removing `(orderBy: order_asc)` resolves successfully.

The queries do not fail on local instances of Neo4j (e.g. Neo4j 4.1.1 launched via docker).
A update to these npm packages did also not provide a change:

```
apollo-server: ^2.25.0
apollo-server-core: ^2.25.0
graphql-tag: ^2.12.4
neo4j-driver: ^4.3.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a problem with a buggy APOC jar in the latest Aura push. I believe all apoc.coll functions and procs may be affected.

It's being worked on, you can monitor status here:

https://status.neo4j.io/

Comment: guess we'll have to wait :)